# Unable to createWriteStream to save downloaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have a function in my [NW.js](http://nwjs.io) app that downloads a bunch of files from the server and saves them in the folder chosen by the user with the names sent from the server.  I do not know the names of the files in advance - the urls I am using are randomly-generated strings that I have gotten from another server, and this server is looking up each hash to see which file it corresponds to.

```
var regexp = /filename=\"(.*)\"/gi;

media_urls.forEach(function(url) {
    var req = client.request(options, function(res) {
        var file_size = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);
        var content_disposition = res.headers['content-disposition'];
        var name = regexp.exec(content_disposition)[1];
        var path = Path.join(save_dir, name);

        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        file.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            req.abort();
        });

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            file.write(chunk);
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            file.end();
        });
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    req.end();
});
```

I keep getting `ENOENT` errors when this code runs.  This doesn't make any sense because the file is supposed to be created *now*, so of course it doesn't exist!

Why am I getting this error instead of having the file downloaded?

Comment: Note that the `Content-Disposition` header isn't just the filename. That's [an additional parameter](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#page-5) that isn't necessarily required -- `Content-Dispostion: attachment; filename=file.ext`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski The particular server is guaranteed to give back filenames. It always gives back the exact filename from the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file names coming from the server had `:`s in them, which is a valid filename character on Linux `ext4`, but not on Windows `ntfs`.

Changing

```
var name = regexp.exec(content_disposition)[1];
```

to

```
var name = regexp.exec(content_disposition)[1].replace(':', '-');
```

solved this particular problem.